# Finding probability of a student passing

Tags: probability

A student took his final exam. He took 3 subjects: Math, English and Science. The grade can be 0-7 for every subject. And if his grades sum up to atleast 10, he pass. However, if he scored 1 or 0 on any subject, he fail. What is the probability that he will pass?

Comment: This question cannot be answered if nothing is known about the probability to get specific scores at specific subjects. Secondly: how far did you get in solving this?

Comment: Also, even given the probability distributions for the three subjects, this question is ill-defined: $\{7, 3, 0\}$ is both a pass and a fail, while $\{3, 3, 3\}$ is neither a pass nor a fail. Or am I missing some convention?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all scores are equally likely, we have:

$$P(\mbox{Pass}) = \dfrac{\mbox{#Pass scores}}{\mbox{#All possible scores}}.$$

$\mbox{#All possible scores} = 8^3 = 512$, because each subject has $8$ possible scores.

Now,
$$\mbox{#Pass scores} = \left(\mbox{#Scores without $0$ or $1$}\right) - \left(\mbox{#Scores without $0$ or $1$ with sum $\lt 10$}\right).$$

Because we want $6$ out of the $8$ possible scores for each subject,

$$\mbox{#Scores without $0$ or $1$} = 6^3 = 216.$$

For the second term, we list the scores without a $0$ or $1$ but still sum to less than $10$. With each score we show the number of ways that score can be arranged among the three subjects. E.g. The score with numbers $2,2,3$ can be $2,2,3$ or $2,3,2$ or $3,2,2$ for Math, English and Science respectively.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\underline{\mbox{Score}} && \underline{\mbox{#Permutations}} \\
2,2,2 && \qquad 1 \\
2,2,3 && \qquad 3 \\
2,2,4 && \qquad 3 \\
2,2,5 && \qquad 3 \\
2,3,3 && \qquad 3 \\
2,3,4 && \qquad 3! = 6 \\
\mbox{Total} && =\quad 19.
\end{eqnarray*}

Combining these two results, we have, $$\mbox{#Pass scores} = 216 - 19 = 197.$$

Therefore, $$P(\mbox{Pass}) = \dfrac{197}{512}.$$